# What am I missing on my code to filter out the cards on the search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, material-ui

In this page of my website im trying to filter out the whole card while doing the search on the blog, but its only filtering out the tags in orange. What am I missing so i can filter out the whole card content?https://drywallmagana.com/blog-reach-view

This is my code (excluding imports, CSS and irrelevant bits so stackoverflow lets me post)

```
const HorizontalCover = props => {

  const { data, className, ...rest } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md'), {
    defaultMatches: true,
  });

  const BlogMediaContent = props => (
    <div className={classes.imageContainer}>
      <Image
        {...props}
        className={classes.image}
        lazyProps={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      />
      <div className={classes.imageCover} />
    </div>
  );

  const [search, setSearch] = useState(``);
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([ '' ]);

  const filteredArticle = tags.filter(li => li.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));



  const BlogContent = props => (

    <div className={clsx(classes.blogContent, 'blog-content')}>
      <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom className={classes.textWhite}>
        {props.title}
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        variant="subtitle1"
        gutterBottom
        className={classes.textWhite}
      >
        {props.subtitle}
      </Typography>


      <div className={classes.tags}>
        {
          // props.tags.map((item, index) => (
          props.tags.filter(li => li.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
            .map((item, key) => (
          <Typography
            variant="caption"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.tag}
            key={''}
          >
            {item}
          </Typography>
        ))}
      </div>


      <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
      <Divider className={classes.divider} />
      <div className={classes.tags}>
        <div className={classes.avatarContainer}>
          <Avatar {...props.author.photo} className={classes.avatar} />
          <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.textWhite}>
            {props.author.name}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography variant="overline" className={classes.textWhite}>
          {props.date}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    </div>

  );

  return (
    <div className={className} {...rest}>

    <Grid container justify="space-between" spacing={isMd ? 4 : 2}>

    <Grid item xs={12}>
    <div className={classes.searchInputContainer} data-aos="fade-up">
        <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
          <OutlinedInput
          className='search'
          type='search'
          placeholder= 'search'
          onChange= {e =>
            setSearch(e.target.value)}

            startAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <Icon
                  fontIconClass="fas fa-search"
                  fontIconColor={colors.blueGrey[900]}
                />
              </InputAdornment>}
          />
        </FormControl>
        <Button
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
          size="large"
          className={classes.searchButton}
          onClick={''}
        >
          Search
        </Button>
      </div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>


    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <div className={classes.tags}>

      {tags
        .filter(li => li.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
        .map((item, key) => (
          <li
          key={''}
          className={classes.tag}>

            {item}{' '}

          </li>
        ))}

      </div>
    </Grid>

      <Grid container spacing={isMd ? 4 : 2}>
        {props.data.map((item, index) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} key={''} data-aos="fade-up">
            <CardProduct

              withShadow
              liftUp
              className={clsx(
                classes.cardProduct,
                index % 2 !== 0 ? classes.cardProductReverse : {},
              )}
              mediaContent={
                <BlogMediaContent {...item.cover} alt={item.title}
                />
              }

              cardContent={
                <BlogContent
                  title={item.title}
                  subtitle={item.subtitle}
                  tags={item.tags}
                  author={item.author}
                  date={item.date}
                />
              }
            />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Seems to me you are filtering tags for each card. But i think what you want is to filter cards bu tags.

Comment: Should I change the position of this part of the code?                         ```props.tags.filter(li => li.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
            .map((item, key) =>```